# Is Wireshark the correct tool as a data (traffic) meter? Something better?

Tags: networking, lubuntu, router, wireshark

My household is allotted 250 gigabytes per month. Someone in my family is using-up all the data. The "traffic meter" on my router (WNDR3700) only tells me total data usage. I want to break it down by MAC address (or some other identifiable way). Is Wireshark the correct tool to do this or do i need something different? (Lubuntu compatible please.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use [wrtbwmon](http://code.google.com/p/wrtbwmon/) but I'm not sure if you could install it on a vanilla WNDR3700...

You could also install the superb Tomato operating system, that can not only break down the usage per client but also set limits and do lots of other wonderful stuff out of the box: http://tomato.groov.pl/?p=379

[image: IP Traffic]